# Bootstrap 4 Confirmation is not working, what is wrong with it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, confirmation

I added bootstrap 4 confirmation in my project but this is not working even I added sources etc...

What is wrong with it?

My code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-confirmation2/dist/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>


<div class="m-4">
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="confirmation">Confirmation</button>
</div>
```

I'm using this "[BS-4-Confirmation](https://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/#installation)" confirmation plugin...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable confirmations via javascript like below.

```
$('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
   rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]'
});
```

I've changed your snippet to work and It will work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-confirmation2/dist/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>

<div class="m-4">
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="confirmation">Confirmation</button>
</div>

<script>
$('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
   rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]'
});
</script>
```